# Can't stop AJAX form submission from opening Action target

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I basically copied an entire form submission code I had up and running on a Website and pasted it into a blank file in order to modify its contents and save some time. IN THEORY, then, if the original file stopped normal form submission from opening up the Action target file while still completing the submission, this one should do the same.

However, I can't get it to work like it did. I can't stop the submission from leaving the current window.

Can anyone please point me toward what I'm doing wrong?

(Aside from the PHP code I'm using the jQuery Validation Plugin, same as I was using in the previous form that worked as expected.)

**Form HTML code:**

```
<form id="form" class="appintro" method="post" action="manageform.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
```

**JS**

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function() { //<-- Handler called by jQuery Validation once form is validated
        $('.msg.sending').fadeIn(200);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function() {
                alert('Success')
    },
            error: function() {
                alert('Failure')
            }
        });
        return false; //<-- This should stop the normal submission...
    }
});
```

I've also already tried calling the AJAX outside of the `validator` code, i.e. using `$("form").submit(function(event)...`, etc. Also tried setting `data` to `form.serializeArray()`, as recommended in some other SO post... Nothing does it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT 1**

I've set up this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JSuUL/1/) to test it out in a simpler version. No matter what I place in AJAX's `url`, I get an error. If I fill the form's `action`, then I can't catch the submission.

Comment: I think e.preventDefault() is better way to go than return false;

Comment: In your debug console, do you know if it is sending the AJAX request? Also are there any errors in your code that appear in the console? You may need to "Preserve the log upon navigation" to see possible errors.

Comment: @Gohn67, Actually, because part of the submission is designed to send an E-Mail with data, I've been testing it out by receiving the E-Mail. So the AJAX is working, the form is being submitted and sent. The only problem is I can't stop the loading of the Action file. I am getting this, however, from the console: "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead." I'm going to test it out and see if it's the issue. Though it seems strange, because the other working example was coded a month back and still works fine...

Comment: @Gohn67, Tried out what the console said but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan, I've tried it but still I can't stop the load.

Comment: Could it be that your form submission triggers the email and not the ajax since you use the same endpoint and form data? For debugging purposes you may want to remove the action attribute from the form and just hardcode the endpoint url. Additionally you may have want to do a console.log("BLAHBLAHBLAH") in your submit handler to double check.

Comment: @Gohn67, yes, I believe you're right: the form was being submitted straight away because, when I leave `action` blank and, instead, fill in the AJAX's `url`, I don't get sent away from the page BUT the form isn't submitted either. I've now tested using the console.log, as you recommended, from inside the submit handler and it works, the handler is acting on the submit. But the strange thing is that now nothing is happening.

Comment: Added a jsFiddle trial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 2**
Ok while fixing some bugs in my version of your js fiddle, I figured what the issue is.

This line is missing the form parameter

```
submitHandler: function() {
```

It should look like this:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
```

Next, to call serialize, you need to wrap make it a jquery object. The form passed in by jquery validate is just a regular form object and not a jquery one. So you need to do this.

```
data: $(form).serialize(),
```

If you call `form.serialize`, you should get this error in Chrome: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLFormElement> has no method 'serialize'`, which could explain why your browser is reloading.

**Edit 1**
I looked at your fiddle and I found some bugs, but I'm not sure they fix your problem. I feel like I just fixed some errors specific to jsfiddle.

Here is a link to an updated fiddle that works: http://jsfiddle.net/JSuUL/6/

Here is the code with some annotations

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    // Need to pass in form variable
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        alert('Sending...')
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',

            // First off changed this to make the request work
            // http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html
            url: '/echo/html/',

            // Instead of form, I used $(form) to reference the form as a jquery object.
            data: $(form).serialize(),

            success: function () {
                alert('Success!')
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Failure!')
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    // I added a "#" here so we can grab the form. Your jsfiddle had $(form)
    $("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            surname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
        }
    });
});
```